# iOS for Android View.GONE setVisibility mode

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have used storyboard with autolayout for my UI design. Basically in android there are three different properties will be there like Visible and Invisible and gone.

**For Example:**

1) Android

```
 mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
 mTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

2) Objective C

```
 UIView *a = [self.view viewWithTag:2]
 I want to process View.GONE...
```

for act as a gone in IOS i have searched from google but i can't able to find the Solution.

Comment: What View.GONE does in android??

Comment: If I am not wrong you don't want to use layout space for View by using View.GONE. Am I right??

Comment: in ios `GONE` not available in this place use `enabled or hidden property`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shin,

Android does not make use of autolayouts to calculate the frame of view components and like CSS (Cascading style sheets) it uses relative values of view components with respect to parent, margin or other peer views to calculate the position of view.

But in iOS when u use auto layouts, you define the constraints which are mathematical expressions and iOS evaluates them to find the actual values for the frames of various components :)

**Whats the Significance of it ?**

Because auto layout constraints are maths expressions, you will have to provide iOS enough data to calculate the unknown values.

Lets consider,

[image]

As you can see the view with pink colour has a fixed horizontal spacing from the green view, so iOS calculates the x position of pink view from the maxX position of green view + horizontal spacing between green and pink view :)

Now assume you call view.GONE on green view and completely remove green view, now iOS will be baffled as it does not know what will be the x position of pink view, now it does not have enough data to calculate the x position of pink view :)

**Does that mean I can never achieve View.GONE in iOS ?**

You can!! only virtually though :P

**HOW??**

Two ways :

**way 1**

You can't remove a view because that will cause it to leave all other view depending on it for their frame calculation un handled. Hence consider setting width and height constraint's constants value of views to "0"

Add height and width constraints to the view which you want to hide and create a IBOutlet to height and width constraints.

Now when you want to hide simply say,

```
self.greenViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0
self.greenViewWidthConstraint.constant = 0
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Yeah!!! Now you have a view whose width and height 0, I mean view exists but does not exist!!

**Way 2**

But then, You dint remove it really using way 1 did you ??? Nope. You can actually remove the view using Way 2

[image]

What I want you to see here that, now I know that if I remove View1, view 2 could not calculate its x position, So I created a Leading constraint from View2 to Parent left margin and set its priority to High and set its constant to 0 :)

Now this constraint will not come into play, as long as required (1000) constraints are good enough to calculate the values, now assume you remove View 1, View 2's frame can't be calculated with Required constraints, hence high constraint kicks in and it says your pink view should be 0 pixel from parents left margin :)

Yeah :) You achieved what you wanted, now you actually removed green view and pink view still not lost its frame :)

**How on earth did you remove green view ??**

Wasn't that the question ?? Sorry, I got carried away :)

You can say `self.greenView.removeFromSuperview()`

Answer (score 1):

On iOS, `visible` and `gone` are done with `hidden = NO` and `hidden = YES`

If you want it to be invisible, set the view `alpha` to `0`.

**edit:** Making a view hidden doesn't make the layout hierarchy ignore it, unless it is in a stack view.

Answer (score 1):

After some googling, I found this:

**View.GONE** - This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.

**View.INVISIBLE** - This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.

And its equivalent in ios is :

**View.GONE** - Uninstalling view. This can be done from storyboard as shown in the below image. You will have to uncheck the checkbox of `Installed`
[image]

**View.INVISIBLE** - View.hidden = true;

Comment: Thats good info .. Unchecking the installed will solve this issue. ..i had to set height constraint to zero to make this happen